# Best data structure for an immutable persistent 3D grid

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, functional-programming

I'm experimenting with writing a game in a functional programming style, which implies representing the game state with a purely functional, immutable data structures.

One of the most important data structures would be a 3D grid representing the world, where objects can be stored at any [x,y,z] grid location. The properties I want for this data structure are:

- **Immutable**
- **Fast persistent updates** - i.e. creation of a new version of the entire grid with small changes is cheap and achieved through structural sharing. The grid may be large so copy-on-write is not a feasible option.
- **Efficient handling of sparse areas / identical values** - empty / unpopulated areas should consume no resources (to allow for large open spaces). Bonus points if it is also efficient at storing large "blocks" of identical values
- **Unbounded** - can grow in any direction as required
- **Fast reads / lookups** - i.e. can quickly retrieve the object(s) at [x,y,z]
- **Fast volume queries**, i.e. quick searches through a region [x1,y1,z1] -> [x2,y2,z2], ideally exploiting sparsity so that empty spaces are quickly skipped over

Any suggestions on the best data structure to use for this?

P.S. I know this may not be the most *practical* way to write a game, I'm just doing it as a learning experience and to stretch my abilities with FP......

Comment: Hi, I think it's worth looking into raytracers (allmost the same *problem* with finding objects) - there are a lot of them implemented with FP languagues and maybe there is one that really takes the performance serious. On the other hand there are workarounds even in haskell to get something like arrays to help with exactly this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try an octtree. The boundary coordinates of each node are implicit in structure placement, and each nonterminal node keep 8 subtree but no data. You can thus 'unioning' to gain space.

I think that **Immutable** and **Unbounded** are (generally) conflicting requirements.
Anyway... to grow a octtree you must must replace the root.

Other requirement you pose should be met.

Comment: all modifying operators on functional data structures return the new root. so there is in fact no conflict between immutable and unbounded.