# 3D grid generation for voxel world: data structure and voxelization

Tags: c#, grid, path-finding, a-star, voxel

I have to implement a path-finding algorithm in a complex 3D environment. My input is a CATIA model which can be exported as stl or stp.

After some research, I reckon my best option is to apply A* Path-finding to a voxelised world.

I am coding in C#.

My questions are:

- which data structure shall I use to represent the discretised world? [Octrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543801/best-data-structure-for-an-immutable-persistent-3d-grid) could be the way to go, but how to convert an stl or stp file into an octree?
- For the time being, I have used [Helix](https://github.com/helix-toolkit) to render my 3D world as a set of spheres on [x,y,z] positions. Are there more optimised strategies for grid rendering?

Comment: Thank you Micky. I narrowed the scope of my questions with more details about the current implementation in Helix.

Comment: That's looking better now thanks